# How to solve the "CIDR Address is not within CIDR Address from VPC" AWS riddle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I know it's a common question, but all the existing answers don't work in my case.

I'm trying to create a subnet on AWS and the current VPC CIDR is `172.31.0.0/16`

Then when I'm entering `10.0.0.0/28` into IPv4 CIDR block it says

CIDR Address is not within CIDR Address from VPC

I also tried `10.0.0.0/16` as suggested and any other number and it doesn't work.

How to solve this riddle?

Why doesn't AWS just offer a default setting there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a subnet within `172.31.0.0/16` then your available IP pool space is between `172.31.0.0` - `172.31.255.255` (excluding reserved addressed).

You cannot have any overlapping ranges with existing subnets and need to include a range between `/16` and `/28`.

Take a look at [cidr.xyz](https://cidr.xyz/), it is great for looking at available CIDR ranges.

Comment: Yes, in fact the tool really helped. Turned out I had a few more subnets, so I calculated the range that was free and in my case it was `172.31.96.0/20` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: No problem glad this helped :)

Comment: No problem @petern, :)

Answer (score 1):

If the VPC CIDR is `172.31.0.0/16`, then all subnets must be within that CIDR. The subnets should always start `172.31.*` since you have **/16** mask. I'd highly recommend reading up on VPC sub-netting, there's more to it, including subnet count and addresses available per subnet: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing